# Binary tree implementation with OOP in Java

Tags: java, class, oop

At the moment im working with binary trees in Java with OOP, but Im confused in some aspects of the OOP. Right now what I am trying to achieve is insert nodes into my tree (manually, ex: (in main) root.left(2); root.right(5), root.left.left(10),etc). All this because I want to try basic operations in a tree and adding elements in this way would make it easier to see.
I am working with 3 classes : Main, BinaryTree and Node

in Node theres only getters and setters and 3 private variables : int integer, Node leftChild, Node rightChild;

My problem is that I dont quite understand where to add nodes because BinaryTree has an object from Nodes and Main has an object from BinaryTree. And if I try to add elements from my object in Main it gives me an error. Im kind of confused.

Comment: Without code it will be very difficult to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-1-introduction/

JAVA Implementation of the logic:

```
class Node 
{ 
    int key; 
    Node left, right; 
  
    public Node(int item) 
    { 
        key = item; 
        left = right = null; 
    } 
} 


class BinaryTree 
{ 
    // Root of Binary Tree 
    Node root; 
  
    // Constructors 
    BinaryTree(int key) 
    { 
        root = new Node(key); 
    } 
  
    BinaryTree() 
    { 
        root = null; 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(); 
  
        /*create root*/
        tree.root = new Node(1); 
  
        /* following is the tree after above statement 
  
              1 
            /   \ 
          null  null     */
  
        tree.root.left = new Node(2); 
        tree.root.right = new Node(3); 
  
        /* 2 and 3 become left and right children of 1 
               1 
             /   \ 
            2      3 
          /    \    /  \ 
        null null null null  */
  
  
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(4); 
        /* 4 becomes left child of 2 
                    1 
                /       \ 
               2          3 
             /   \       /  \ 
            4    null  null  null 
           /   \ 
          null null 
         */
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

think of each node as a separate tree.
So in the insert operation by iterating over the tree starting from the root until you find the parent of the node you are inserting.

This might help to explain it better: (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-in-a-binary-tree-in-level-order/)